# How to set ghci options for cabal repl?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, cabal, ghci

I have a haskell project which I compile with `-Werror` by default. This means that when I run `cabal repl` it runs with the option `-Werror` turned on. This means that for example when I evaluate `2 + 2` I get the following error message:

```
<interactive>:2:3: Warning:
Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Integer'
  (Num a0) arising from a use of `+'
In the expression: 2 + 2
In an equation for `it': it = 2 + 2
```

So I need a way to turn on the option, `-w` or maybe `-Wwarn` on by default for `cabal repl`. How do I do this? Also what are the default flags for `ghci`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set GHCi options in your `~/.ghci` file:

```
:set -w
```

This overrides the `-Wall` from `cabal repl` for me.

My understanding is that `ghci` has the same defaults a `ghc`: it's like calling the compiler with no flags. `cabal repl` gets its defaults from your `.cabal` file (like `ghc-options: -Wall`), but this is overridden by your `~/.ghci` file.

You can also create a `.ghci` file in your project directory, with per-project settings there. However, this seems to interact awkwardly with my global `~/.ghci` file: adding a `set -Wall` does not override the `:set -w` from the global one. I'm not sure if this behavior is intended or I'm just misunderstanding something.