# Different warnings settings in cabal file and in repl

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I generally want to make sure I use either explicit import lists or qualified imports in Haskell, but frequently while making changes I just import everything from a module and then need a reminder to fix it up before I commit. So I've added `ghc-options: -Wmissing-import-lists` to my project's cabal file, which works great.

However, during development I also use the repl a lot, and I usually want far less warnings in my repl session than I do when compiling my real code. So I had the same idea suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323686/how-to-set-ghci-options-for-cabal-repl); use a (project-local) `.ghci` file that turns off many of the warnings I set in my cabal file, including `-Wno-missing-import-lists`.

The trouble is `cabal repl` does this:

```
Preprocessing library for example-0.1.0.0..
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

<interactive>:1:1: warning: [-Wmissing-import-lists]
    The module ‘Prelude’ does not have an explicit import list
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/ben/src/example/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/ben/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Example          ( src/Example.hs, interpreted )
*Example
λ
```

It applies `-Wmissing-import-lists` during its own implicit import of the `Prelude` before it even tries to read my .ghci file disabling the warning.<sup>1</sup>

I assume this would also be a problem with any other options that GHCi applies before reading any .ghci files (are there others?). So is there any other way to specify in the cabal file that some GHC options are only for building, not for repling?

---

<sup>1</sup> It's particularly irksome because building `Example.hs` with that warning doesn't actually complain about missing imports from the implicit `Prelude` import, and if I explicitly import `Prelude` with an import list then I still get the warning with `cabal repl` from its own import, even though those imports aren't actually in scope at the prompt!

Comment: What if you ran ghci with `-XNoImplicitPrelude`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz If you use `cabal repl --ghc-options ...`, then the `...` is in effect for compiling all of the modules in my project that the repl loads. So `-XNoImplicitPrelude` doesn't really help. `-Wno-missing-import-lists`, though it's a bit irksome to do so manually on every invocation (I can make an alias, sure, but also configure any tooling that invokes `cabal repl`, etc).